# Show that $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \exists x P(x) \implies\exists x Q(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> show that $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \exists x P(x)
>  \implies\exists x Q(x)$
>
> $$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \exists x P(x) \implies 
>   (P(y) \rightarrow Q(y)) \wedge P(y) \quad (\text{using universal
>  specification}) \\ \implies\;\; Q(y) \quad (\text{using modus
> ponens}) \\ \implies\;\; \exists x Q(x)\quad (\text{using
> existential generalization})$$

Hi. I am confused about a proof in my discrete mathematics textbook. I have written the question and proof above. My textbook uses $\implies$ to mean tautologically implies. And, $\rightarrow$ means a normal if then statement. Right, so my textbook states that

> **Universal Specification:**   Let $P(x)$ be a predicate on x and the set $A$ be the universe of discourse for $x$ . If we assume $P(x)$ is
> true for all $x \in A$ , then it can be concluded that the predicate
> $P$ is also true for any arbitrary element $y \in A$, that is,
> $\forall x P(x) \implies P(y)$

By this US, I can see how $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \implies 
  (P(y) \rightarrow Q(y))$. However, I don't understand how US implies that the $\exists x P(x)$ part implies $P(y)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think I get that part. But it's the parts with the underbrace that doesn't make sense to me. How does US imply those parts? $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \underbrace{\exists x P(x)} \implies 
  (P(y) \rightarrow Q(y)) \wedge  \underbrace{P(y)}$

Comment: In the formula on the left, $x$ is followed by the quantifier $\forall$ (and also $\exists$) so it's a **parameter**, not a free variable. And for any parameter in a formula, if you replace it with other variable you also need to replace all of its appearances in the formula with that variable.

Comment: The details of this proof depend on how exactly Existential and Universal Introduction/Generalization and Existential and Universal Elimination/Instantiation/Specification are defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying existential instantiation to
$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \land\exists x P(x)
 \implies\exists x Q(x)$ gives
$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \land P(y)$ and now using universal specification we get
$(P(y) \rightarrow Q(y)) \land P(y)$ from which $Q(y)$ follows.
To finish, apply existential generalization.

Comment: Ok, thanks I get it. I wonder why the textbook didn't include the step of applying the  existential instantiation and just instead put both steps under the umbrella of universal specification.

Comment: I guess you could do $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \land\exists x P(x)$ which is the same as $ \exists x P(x)  \land \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ which implies 
$ \exists x  ( P(x)  \land (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ from which we get $P(y) \land (P(y) \rightarrow Q(y))$, but that is certainly not what was written above.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange how the author combines both universal and existential specification in one step. In my proof here, using a form of natural deduction, I do existential specification on line 4, then universal specification on line 5.

Plain text version:

```
1   ALL(x):[P(x) => Q(x)] & EXIST(x):P(x)
    Premise

2   ALL(x):[P(x) => Q(x)]
    Split, 1

3   EXIST(x):P(x)
    Split, 1

4   P(y)
    E Spec, 3

5   P(y) => Q(y)
    U Spec, 2

6   Q(y)
    Detach, 5, 4

7   EXIST(x):Q(x)
    E Gen, 6

8   ALL(x):[P(x) => Q(x)] & EXIST(x):P(x)
    => EXIST(x):Q(x)
    Conclusion, 1
```